# Laravel: Weird Unexpected 'endif'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to load some data from the DB into my View and I have coded this:

```
@forelse($wallets as $wallet)
    <td>{{ $wallet->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $wallet->name }}</td>
    <td>
    @if(($wallet->is_active)==1)
        Active
    @else
        Deactive
    @endif
    </td>
    <td>
    @if(($wallet->is_cachable)==1)
        Cachable
    @else
        Un Cachable
    @endif
    </td>
@endforelse
```

But I get this:

**syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)**

However, as you can see I have closed the `if`s properly by saying: `@endif`

So what is going wrong here?

Comment: You need an `@empty` somewhere between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for `@forelse` is wrong.

You need to place an `@empty` somewhere in-between which will be rendered when `$wallets` is empty:

```
@forelse($wallets as $wallet)

  <td>{{ $wallet->title }}</td>
  <td>{{ $wallet->name }}</td>
  <td>
    @if(($wallet->is_active)==1)
      Active
    @else
      Deactive
    @endif
  </td>
  <td>
    @if(($wallet->is_cachable)==1)
      Cachable
    @else
      Un Cachable
    @endif
 </td>

@empty    

  <p>No wallet data available</p>

@endforelse
```

[Looping in blade.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)